# hashtable and getting the key of words

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I want to store some words in a hash table using open addressing and double hashing

the problem is that I have been asked to use base-128 radix system calculated using horners rule to get the key of the word but I have no idea how to implement base-128 radix system in java. could anyone help me?

Comment: You're asking somebody to write it for you, not help you.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: We're not a *write-my-code-for-me* service; show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: I respect to all friends, but it is not like that I don't need you to write my code and I searched about that too and even I had a basic Idea. However I was not sure if it is the best one so I asked it here. Anyway, thanks for jumping to conclusion and blaming me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few pointers:

- **Horner's rule is a polynomial evaluation strategy**; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method)
- The idea of using base-128 is to **encode letters (probably from the core ASCII character set) as numbers**. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) again.

So basically what you do, given a key `foobar`, is too **compute the associated numeric values** (`[102, 111, 111, 98, 97, 114]`), then consider them to be the **coefficients of a polynomial** (`102 + 111*X + 111*X^2 + 98*X^3 + 97*X^4 + 114*X^5`), and **evaluate that polynomial at a specific point** (of your choosing, say `7`, yielding `2188827`), which **yields your hash value**.

Note that evaluating a polynomial quickly produces **large values** ; one common solution is **taking the modulus of the result**, choosing a large enough prime modulus. Also note that due to modular arithmetic laws, **you can take the modulus at every step of Horner's algorithm**. In the previous example, assuming you chose `39019` as your primer number, you'd get `3763`.

That's a **very simple implementation of a checksum** (far from being cryptographically secure btw)

Comment: Thanks example helped to clarify issue better